# How to set NotificationChannel importance to urgent by program?

Tags: android

I want to implement chat notification() like whatsapp (Whatsapp don't know how but reset the Group Message channel importance (Android O) to Urgent).
All going good only i am not able to set NotificationChannel importance to Urgent programmatically.

Here is my work for the Notifications.

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Const.Type.KEY, Const.Type.NOTIFICATION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "alert_001")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_s)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("Booking Request")
            .setContentText(content)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Const.Channel.Id.ALERT_001,
                    Const.Channel.Name.BOOKING_ALERT,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            /* Here is no constant like NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_URGENT
             * and i can't even put the another integer value, It not obeying the rules*/

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
        }
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

While i am changing the, JSON response for notification like below,

```
{
  priority=high,
  message=msgmsg,
  source_lat=22.751552,
  source_lng=75.895745,
  user_detail={},
}
```

At least it is working like **NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH**, But not like **URGENT**.
I don't know how whatsapp implemented that can override the **URGENT** importance even if user changes it manually.

Comment: refer this link https://medium.com/cr8resume/notification-in-android-8-0-oreo-implementing-notification-channels-d65b0f81ca50

Comment: if you want then provide code for how to create simple notification with channel.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hack:

```
private String ensureChannelAudibility(String channelMainId, String channelName, Uri soundUri) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(App.instance);
    List<NotificationChannel> channels = notificationManager.getNotificationChannels();
    NotificationChannel existingChanel = null;
    int count = 0;
    for (NotificationChannel channel : channels) {
        String fullId = channel.getId();
        if (fullId.contains(channelMainId)) {
            existingChanel = channel;
            String[] numbers = extractRegexMatches(fullId, "\\d+");
            if (numbers.length > 0) {
                count = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (existingChanel != null) {
        if (existingChanel.getImportance() < NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT) {
            notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(existingChanel.getId());
            existingChanel = null;
        }
    }

    if (existingChanel == null) {
        String newId = channelMainId+'_'+(count+1);
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(newId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        return newId;
    } else {
        return existingChanel.getId();
    }
}

//Show the notification with channel id returned by the method above

public String[] extractRegexMatches(String source, String regex) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.add(matcher.group());
        }

        String[] result = new String[matches.size()];
        matches.toArray(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Normally you can only set channel importance when creating it. Once the user changes it, you can not change it back programmatically. The code above tricks the system. It detects if channels importance is lower than needed and if it is, it deletes it and creates another one with a different id. Thus the system things that it's a different channel needed for something else.

So let's say you have a channel with "channelMainId" = wolf. A (wolf_1) channel will be created. Once the user changes it's settings, next channel will be (wolf_2), then
wolf_3, wolf_4 ... wolf_xxxxxxxxxxxx.

Comment: You might want to add a `try/catch` to `notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(existingChanel.getId());` because on newer Android versions this is sometimes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
        String channelId = "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID";
        String channelName = "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        final NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                            this,channelId)
                                            .setContentTitle("APP_NAME")
                                            .setSmallIcon(//set any Icon)
                                            .setContentText("TEXT")
                                            .setAutoCancel(true);

final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//      for oreo-notification
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                                                channelId, channelName, importance);
                                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                                    }
```

Thanks